# Teradata TPT remove trailing period or escape character for single quote

Tags: teradata

I have simple TPT export command, as you can see I'm trying to remove the trailing period from the column

TRIM(trailing '.' from PRTY_ID)

Since the "VARCHAR SelectStmt " is starting with the single-quote I cannot use single-quote in "TRIM(trailing '.' from PRTY_ID)"

Is there a way to escape singe-quote from the select statement or any other way to remove trailing  period. Thanks.

```
DEFINE JOB EXPORT_DELIMITED_FILE
DESCRIPTION 'Export rows from a Teradata table to a delimited file'
(
    DEFINE SCHEMA FILE_SCHEMA
    (
        COL1 VARCHAR
    );

    DEFINE OPERATOR SQL_SELECTOR
    TYPE SELECTOR
    SCHEMA FILE_SCHEMA
    ATTRIBUTES
    (
        VARCHAR PrivateLogName = 'selector_log',
        VARCHAR TdpId = 'prod',
        VARCHAR LogonMech = 'LDAP',
        VARCHAR UserName = 'user1',
        VARCHAR UserPassword = 'XXXX',
        VARCHAR SelectStmt =  '  
            select TOP 100 
                trim ( 
                    cast ( 
                            ( 
                                trim(cast(cast(TRIM(trailing '.' from EMP_ID) AS CHAR(100))) 
                            ) 
                        as  CHAR(10000)) 
                )
             from DP_TRM.V_ANSWER_FACT ; ',
        VARCHAR ReportModeOn = 'Y'
    );

    DEFINE OPERATOR FILE_WRITER
    TYPE DATACONNECTOR CONSUMER
    SCHEMA *
    ATTRIBUTES
    (
        VARCHAR PrivateLogName = 'dataconnector_log',
        VARCHAR DirectoryPath = 'T:\Manjesh\Athena\Output\V_SURVEY_ANSWER_FACT\',
        VARCHAR FileName = 'V_SURVEY_ANSWER_FACT*.csv',
        VARCHAR Format = 'Delimited',
        VARCHAR IndicatorMode = 'N', 
        VARCHAR OpenMode = 'Write',
        VARCHAR TextDelimiter = '|'
    );

    APPLY TO OPERATOR (FILE_WRITER)
    SELECT * FROM OPERATOR (SQL_SELECTOR);
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You escape it like a single quote in a string literal in SQL by doubling it:

```
VARCHAR SelectStmt =  '  
    select TOP 100 
        trim ( 
            cast ( 
                    ( 
                        trim(cast(cast(TRIM(trailing ''.'' from EMP_ID) AS CHAR(100))) 
                    ) 
                as  CHAR(10000)) 
        )
     from DP_TRM.V_ANSWER_FACT ; ',
```

But why do you do multiple CAST to CHAR and then TRIM instead of directly CASTing to a VarChar?

And `EMP_ID` is probably defined as Decimal and the trailing period is added because of the default format `Z(x)9.`, you could CAST it to an INTEGER, then there's no need for TRIM.